# Should abstract be `titlepage`? (KOMA-Script)

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering, abstract

I'm using the KOMA-Script scrbook class to typeset my dissertation. My main question is: should the abstract be put in a `titlepage` environment?

Right now, I'm doing the following.

```latex
\frontmatter

\maketitle

\addchap*{Abstract}
\setcounter{page}{1}

Sunt Lorem proident nostrud amet quis ut. Ut anim officia culpa eiusmod nulla duis ipsum. Minim et eiusmod aliquip mollit veniam ad deserunt magna consectetur. Velit enim exercitation Lorem ea. Sit nisi nulla nulla occaecat laborum adipisicing ad veniam ex ipsum in mollit. Magna ipsum ut in excepteur aliqua voluptate nostrud incididunt anim do enim sunt ad officia. Velit nulla nulla excepteur Lorem pariatur commodo aliqua magna occaecat commodo ipsum cillum sint.
```

This way, the 'abstract' page is the first numbered page. If it were a titlepage, obviously it wouldn't get a number (by default). Please do let me know if there's a better way to control the numbering, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

See KOMA-script manual (in Englisch: `texdoc scrguien`, German version: `texdoc scrguide`), p. 72:

> Books typically use a different kind of summary. There, you usually place  an appropriate chapter at the beginning or the end of the work.
> This chapter is often combined with either the introduction or a
> description of a larger prospectus. Therefore, the scrbook class has
> no abstract environment. A summary chapter is also recommended for
> reports in a wider sense, such as a Master’s thesis or Ph.D.
> dissertation. See the commands \chapter*, \addchap, and \addchap*
> documented in section 3.16, from page 105.

So no, don't put the abstract of your thesis into the titlepage environment.

Comment: Thank you. As it happens though, the layout requirements (which I just found) for this dissertation require the abstract to be on the second page, followed by a signed declaration of authorship, acknowledgements, the table of contents (and other tables), and only then the first chapter proper. So it seems that even recommendation of `\addchap` doesn't apply to well. Certainly, it looks like the abstract page should not be numbered.